# Setting PHP form action using IF

Tags: php, html

How can i conditionally set PHP form action?.
i have the following drop down option, when 2WD and 4WD selected i want to redirect or go to A.php otherwise the other one MFWD selected to open page B

```
 <form action="page.php">
    <select name="tractor">
      <option value="2wd">2WD</option>
      <option value="mfwd">MFWD</option>
      <option value="4wd">4WD</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit">
```

```
     here is the whole code
    <?php ob_start ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>

  <form method="post">
    <select name="tractor">
     <option value="2wd"><a href="iar7.php">2WD</a></option>
      <option value="mfwd">MFWD</option>
         <option value="4wd">4WD</option>

   </select>
   <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="cmd_submit" />

 </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cmd_submit'])){
    if($_POST['tractor'] == "2wd" || $_POST['tractor'] == "4wd"){
         //redirect here
         header('location:iar7.php');
    }else{
         header('location:iar-calculator.php');
     }
   }
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: move the php code above the `html` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this. omit the `action` attribute and add a `method="post"`..  otherwise you need to add a `get` method there... and get the query string of the `tractor` to do a conditional statement on your `action attribute`....

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="post">
 <select name="tractor">
  <option value="2wd">2WD</option>
  <option value="mfwd">MFWD</option>
  <option value="4wd">4WD</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="cmd_submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['cmd_submit'])){
        if($_POST['tractor'] == "2wd" || $_POST['tractor'] == "4wd"){
             //redirect here
             header('location:a.php');
        }else{
             header('location:b.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sam i get 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by '

Comment: @Funk can you add `ob_start` on the first line of your file? or move the php code above your `html` tag.. here read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: I added the whole code i am working on at the bottom of my question

Comment: @Funk you need to move the php code above html tag i'll edit it for you.